# IPython Notebook: how to display() multiple objects without newline

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Currently when I use `display()` function in the IPython notebook I get newlines inserted between objects:

```
>>> display('first line', 'second line') 
first line
second line
```

But I would like the `print()` function's behaviour where everything is kept on the same line, e.g.:

```
>>> print("all on", "one line")
all on one line
```

Is there a method of changing `display` behaviour to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, `display` cannot prevent newlines, in part because there are no newlines to prevent.  Each displayed object gets its own `div` to sit in, and these are arranged vertically. You might be able to adjust this by futzing with CSS, but I wouldn't recommend that.

The only way you could really get two objects to display side-by-side is to build your own object which encapsulates multiple displayed objects, and display that instead.

For instance, your simple string case:

```
class ListOfStrings(object):
    def __init__(self, *strings):
        self.strings = strings

    def _repr_html_(self):
        return ''.join( [
           "<span class='listofstr'>%s</span>" % s
           for s in self.strings
           ])

display(ListOfStrings("hi", "hello", "hello there"))
```

[example notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/5915531)

Comment: This does not work with `Math`, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly reverse problem (`\n` not working) and I solved it from py side. You can use for example this

```py
a = 'first line', 'second line'  # This converts to tuple
display(" ".join(a))
```

With this result

```
'first line second line'
```