# Print different elements on the same line, with different colors in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use `colorama` in Jupyter notebook and it doesn't do anything. However when try it in console it works fine. Here my sample code:

```
from sys import stdout
from colorama import Fore

# Option 1
stdout.write(Fore.RED + "Test")

# Option 2
print(Fore.GREEN + "Test")
```

My goal is to print different elements on the same line, with different colors.

I'm on Linux (Ubuntu 20) and using Python 2.7. The same issue occurs when I try it in python3

Comment: Just FYI, avoid using python2 if possible, since it is [no longer maintained](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/).

Comment: @AdamBoinet  "The same issue occurs when I try it in python3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some markdown here, using `Markdown` and `display` from the `IPython.display` module.

I believe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46934204/8286364) may be what you're looking for.

---

**EDIT**

Based on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17439972/8286364) to [the question you referenced to in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439176/ipython-notebook-how-to-display-multiple-objects-without-newline), here is some code that prints different elements *on the same line, with the same color*:

```py
In [1]:     class ListOfColoredStrings(object):
                def __init__(self, *args):
                    """
                    Expected input:
                    args = ["word_1", "color_1"], ["word_2", "color_2"]

                    :param args: pairs of [word, color], both given as strings
                    """
                    self.strings = [a[0] for a in args]
                    self.colors = [a[1] for a in args]

                def _repr_html_(self):
                    return ''.join( [
                       "<span class='listofstr' style='color:{}'>{}</span>"
                            .format(self.colors[i], self.strings[i])
                       for i in range(len(self.strings))
                       ])

In [2]:     %%html
            <style type='text/css'>
            span.listofstr {
              margin-left: 5px
            }
            </style>

In [3]:     ListOfColoredStrings(["hi", "red"], ["hello", "green"])
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Yes, that works great until I need each print being on a new line But I need different colored characters be side by side and  
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439176/ipython-notebook-how-to-display-multiple-objects-without-newline) shows it's too complicated

Comment: @Ivan I just updated my answer, I hope this is what you were looking for

Comment: Yeah, this way might be a bit long, but it perfectly solves the problem so thank you very much !